# Conversion from UIColor with alpha component to CGColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

This piece of code works fine

```
self.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

While this throws an exception in my drawRect function

```
self.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2].CGColor;
```

drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor); //exception here
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect);

}
```

What's the issue?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"

Comment: Hmm... Try my answer. If that doesn't work try just not using the property in draw rect. The colour shouldn't be the issue here. Also, how are you defining the fillColor property?

Comment: I was defining it as CGColorRef. Now that I checked out I found out that CGColorRef is meant to be opaque. Will try to find a way replace CGColorRef with something. Thanks!

Comment: Define it as UIColor then and use FillColor.CGColor in draw rect.

Comment: Just to clarify. You seem to be assuming you can't use transparency here. That is not correct at all.

Comment: update my answer for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It looks like the error is from the way the property is defined.

Try defining it this way...

```
@property UIColor *fillColor;
```

Then in drawRect you can use...

```
fillColor.CGColor
```

I have done this hundreds of times. Alpha values don't make any difference.

Comment: Still throws the same exception. I guess it doesn't like having an alpha component. Perhaps UIViews are not supposed to have transparency?

Comment: @EduardAvetisyan No, like I said I the comment I don't think the colour is the issue here. It may be how you are defining the property. Also, try not using the property and just using the colour. Also, of course UIViews have transparency. How do you think UILabels show the background behind the text etc...

Comment: Is there any way of adding alpha component to CGColor? I am getting black on giving 0 alpha :sad:

Comment: @Koushik if you are having trouble with something you are best off asking a question about it. But yeah, you can set the alpha of a CGColor. It's in the init method.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for replying